Execute a remote shell script from within screen via SSH and view stdout in one command
Couldn't find an answer for my particular use-case in the hours I've unsuccessfully researched this.
I have a script located on machine B. I am aiming to run a command on machine A that establishes an SSH session, runs the script within screen, and shows me the stdout as if I were running the screen command directly on machine B.
Hours of trial and error have produced the below command, which has so far produced the best results I've gotten. It seems to successfully start the screen session which I can resume via SSH, but the script does not execute.
ssh -f user@machineB 'screen -dm sh /Users/user/Bin/script.sh; exec sh'

An alternate iteration of this command (which I did not record) seemed to execute the script, but when I tried to resume the active screen session, screen returned error $TERM too long - sorry.
I am running macOS on machines A and B, and using macOS's built-in screen binary. I'd like to stick with native tools if at all possible, even if screen isn't the best solution here.
Noticed that nohup might be a more simple solution, but I get the feeling my current *nix fundamentals knowledge makes approaching nohup a greater challenge.
I appreciate any nudge in the right direction!

Does it specifically have to be "showing stdout" (as plain text, I assume), as opposed to attaching to the screen in the normal way?

Attaching to the screen normally is preferable. I guess I got hung up on stdout from all the spaghetti I've been throwing at the wall.

Connect with the -t option. This enables tty allocation (which is usually enabled for interactive connections but not for single-command ones) and will allow regular use of Screen and all other interactive programs.
ssh -t user@machineB "screen sh /Users/user/Bin/script.sh"


Thank you for the suggestion. I am fairly certain I tried it before, as this result is familiar to me:
[screen is terminating]
Connection to machineB closed.
I couldn't find a way to get screen to produce a more verbose error.
